# How to export mssql data to ftp site?

Tags: sql-server

I need to schedule daily export data from `mssql` to a `csv file` on to a ftp site.  Can I create one single ssis package to export the data to a file then ftp out to a ftp site on a schedule?  How to do it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have included the answer along with the question :). Yes, use the SSIS package to do the needful. This way it will be easy for the maintenance and for further enhancements.